# Shipping fee categories base and set max shipping fee

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to set shipping fee base on product categories and apply max shipping fee.

Ex: I have 10 categories of product (Category 1, 2, 3, ... 10).

**Conditions**

1. If customer buy from Categories 1:

   - 1 pcs shipping fee is 100
   - 2 pcs shipping fee is 200
   - more than 2 pcs shipping fix at 200
2. If customer buy from Categories 2-10:

   - 1 pcs shipping fee is 70
   - 2 pcs shipping fee is 140
   - more than 2 pcs shipping fee is 200

**3. If customer buy mix from Categories 1-10:**

- 1 pcs from Categories 1 is 100
- 1 pcs from Categories 2-10 is 70

**Max shipping fee is 200, mean buy any pcs shipping fee = 200**

Is this possible to set with default Magento promotion ?

Right now I custom code, but it effect to system when I set free shipping. so I want to convert back and using default Magento rule.

Or any extension support this kind of task ?

Thanks